# Loading JW Player on a hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm using JW Player to show a Flash video (although it will soon have HTML5 sources where browser support allows).

Until the user takes an action on the page, the video needs to be invisible (but loaded). Once they take that action, the video `div` is shown and I'd like to `play()` the video as immediately as possible.

Here's my `setup()` call. `<div id="video">` is hidden in my CSS file, as is JW Player's `<div id="video_wrapper">` (both set to `display: none;` initially).

```
jwplayer("video").setup({
  playlist: [
    {
      sources: [
        { file: 'http://example.com/video.flv' }
      ]
    }
  ],
  controls: false,
  wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

And some time later, I'm doing this:

```
$('#video').show();
$('#video_wrapper').show();
jwplayer().play();
```

I don't get any errors in the console and the video plays fine if I don't first hide the containing `div`s in my CSS file.

Does JW Player not fire its `setup()` method on a hidden element? And, if not, how should I achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

See if the solution here works for you:

[Unable to play audio when JWPlayer is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070196/unable-to-play-audio-when-jwplayer-is-hidden)

Position the containing div so that it is no longer visible, then call the setup function on it. Your show function will have to be a little more complex to change the display settings back to how you want them to be.