# Unable to play audio when JWPlayer is hidden

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am currently trying to get JWPlayer to play audio files when the user interface is hidden. It works fine for video (plays the sound from the video) but for some reason, when I use the same technique for playing audio files nothing happens when I click my custom play button.

This code plays the sound from the video as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
    <input onclick="jwplayer('player').play();" type="button" value="Play the hidden video!!!" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jwplayer("player").setup({
            levels: [
            { file: "VideoTest001.mp4" },
            { file: "VideoTest001.ogv" },
            { file: "VideoTest001.webm" }
            ]
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code plays audio fine (but the player is visible):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <input onclick="jwplayer('player').play();" type="button" value="Play the hidden audio!!!" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jwplayer("player").setup({
            levels: [
                { file: "AudioTest.mp3" },
                { file: "AudioTest.wav" }
            ]
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I add the `<div style="display: none;">...</div>` the audio no longer plays.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
    <input onclick="jwplayer('player').play();" type="button" value="Play the hidden audio!!!" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jwplayer("player").setup({
            levels: [
                { file: "AudioTest.mp3" },
                { file: "AudioTest.wav" }
            ]
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help? I would like the audio to play when the JWPlayer user interface is hidden.

Comment: Btw: dunno if it is intentional or not, but your website kicks ass with its 404 (Not found) image ;)

Comment: I believe you can also just set the player to 1x1 px and it will work. If it is totally hidden it won't work.

Comment: @KevinBrydon The http://goo.gl/IgLRD one that appears randomly :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: @Walialu Ha. That's a great photo! Bug noted. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the content isn't loaded when the div's display style is set to none.

Try setting something like this

```
<div style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px;">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
```